# VueJs Vuetify Click on table row event not reading item

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

i am new to VueJs and Vuetify and i have a script that read data from a Json and display it into a Table.is a glossary type app. I have the option to select from different languages to be shown into the table. The problem is that when i click on a row i would like to display into a popup (alert) the item information. What i did is not working at all, is just showing the Alert popup but without information.

The format of the Json is:

```
{"glossary":[
{"id":2,"English":{"term":"contact","definition":"the state of physical touching"},"Vietnamese":{"term":"tiếp xúc"},"Simplified_Chinese":{"term":"接触"},"Arabic":{"term":"ملامسة"},"Swahili":{"term":"mgusano"}}]}





    <v-data-table dense light :headers="selectedHeaders" :item-key="id" @click:row="showAlert(item)" :items="glossary.glossary" class="elevation-1" :single-expand="true" :disable-sort=true :search="search">
     <template #item.ar.term="{item}">
      <div style="text-align:right;">
       <span>{{item.ar.term}}</span>
      </div>
     </template>
</v-data-table>

<script>
import About from '@/views/About.vue'
import json from '@/assets/data/glossary.json'
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: { About },
  data () {
    return {
      publicPath: process.env.BASE_URL,
      glossary: json,
      search: '',
      value: [],
      expanded: [],
      selectedHeaders: [],
      dialog: false,
      headers: [
        { text: 'English', value: 'English.term' },
        { text: 'Vietnamese', value: 'Vietnamese.term' },
        { text: 'Arabic', value: 'Arabic.term' },
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    filter(value, search, item) {
      return value != null &&
        search != null &&
        typeof value === 'string' &&
        value.toString().toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLocaleLowerCase()) !== -1
    },
    showAlert(a){
      if (event.target.classList.contains('btn__content')) return;
      alert('Extra Information:! \n'+this.English.term );
      console.log(this);
    }
  watch: {
    value(val) {
      this.selectedHeaders = val ;
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.selectedHeaders = this.headers;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: ShowAlert is passing `a` which is the item as a variable but it's not used. `this` just returns the vue object

Comment: Then what do you recommand to use to show the value inside the item? i tried with a.English.term and is get error.

Comment: Try `console.log(a)` and see if the result you want is in there

Comment: sorry for my limited knowledge but how can i check the console.log if i am remote on a Ubuntu Azure VM with only SSH access?

Comment: I've added an answer and an example that should help. I'm not sure what your setup is like but I would assume if you are running this from the terminal then you should be able to see the console.log

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `a` which is the item passed. `this` just returns the vue object. What you might want is this

```
 showAlert(a){
      if (a.target.classList.contains('btn__content')) return;
      alert('Extra Information:! \n'+a.English.term );
      console.log(a);
    }
```

Here is a codepen that I found that should help you understand it better https://codepen.io/nsiggel/pen/KRdGgE. Note: I did not write this codepen.